# Electron silent printing doest resolve promises or async await

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an app on Electron that is suppposed to print silently with a thermal printer. The main issue here is that the promise is never resolved when the method is called (whether it's done from the console or the button) when it's configured on silent.

Here are the codes for the call

```
ipcMain.on("print", async (event, html) => {
    try {
      let impresion = new BrowserWindow({ show: false }); //Se crea la ventana de impresión invsible para el usuario
      impresion.loadURL(
        "data:text/html;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(html)
      ); //Se carga el contenido HTML proporcionado en la ventana oculta
      impresion.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
        //Se espera a que la ventana de impresion termine de cargar el contenido HTML
        impresion.webContents.print(
          //Se especifican opciones de impresion
          {
            printBackground: false,
            silent: true,
          },
          (status, error) => {
            if(status){
              event.sender.send("res-print", { status }); //Envía mensajes indicando el resultado o cualquier error ocurrido
            }else{
              event.sender.send("res-print", error);
            }
            impresion.close();
            win = null;
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (error) {
      //Manejo de errores, en este caso de la impresión de renderizacion
      console.log(error);
      event.sender.send("error-print", { error: error.message });
    }
  });
```

And the method that works with the button

```
function imprimirHTML(html) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        ipcRenderer.send('print', html);
        console.log('first message');
        ipcRenderer.on('res-print', (event, arg) => {
            console.log('print message');
            resolve(arg);
            console.log(arg);
        });
        ipcRenderer.on('error-print', (event, arg) => {
            console.log('error print message');
            reject(arg)
            console.log(arg);
        });
    })
}
```

I've tried to downgrade the Electron version, using async await, and promises with then and catch, but that doesnt work either...

Comment: So you're basing the claim that the promise never resolves on the circumstance the window isn't closed automatically, right? Or does it close and you just don't get the event response from the main process?